# XML Start/End Date

Tags: xml, date, time

Is there a way to add a start and end date to the rotating images inside this XML file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<rotator>
  <panel>
    <number>1</number>
    <image>https://media.socastsrm.com/wordpress/wp-content/blogs.dir/2463/files/2021/02/music-and-miracles-radiothon-wtvy-fb-twitter.jpg</image>
    <url>https://955wtvy.com/donate/</url>
    <redirect>n</redirect>
  </panel>   

  <panel>
    <number>2</number>
    <image>https://media.socastsrm.com/wordpress/wp-content/blogs.dir/2463/files/2020/07/Jerome-and-DC.jpg</image>
    <url>https://955wtvy.com/mornings/</url>
    <redirect>n</redirect>
  </panel>
</rotator>
```

Comment: If all you want is an XML file with start and end dates, then you could add `<start_date>` and `<end_date>` elements to each panel, and put values into them. If you want those values to do something, you need to tell us what software component or platform you're working with. What's using this XML file?

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole It's an XML file that I upload to an FTP and it's used to display rotating images on our mobile apps. Would it look like <start_date>2021-2-22</start_date> after <panel>?

Comment: the specific syntax I made up because the request wasn't clear. I may not be the person who answers this question, the question came up for review and I'm suggesting that you need to provide details to help other members answer your question. We know nothing about your mobile apps, for example. What platform/language? Try to be as specific as you can and people will be in a position to help you.